# Using apply for multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I need to create 2 new columns based one existing 2 columns. I am trying to do it using 1 single apply function instead of 2 apply functions separately.
Initial Df for example is as follows:

```
    ID1 ID2
0   1   11
1   2   12
2   3   13
3   4   14
4   5   15
5   6   16
6   7   17
7   8   18
8   9   19
9   10  20
```

Next I try to create 2 new columns using the below method:

```
def funct(row):
    list1 = row.values
    print(list1[0])
    return row

df[['s1','s2']] = df[['ID1',"ID2"]].apply(lambda row: funct(row))
```

The issue is that I want to access the values individually which I am unable to do so . Here i tried converting into list but when I do list[0] i get

```
1
11
```

How to access 1 and 11 above? how should I index to access individual series value when I send two series together using apply?
**NOTE: the content of funct() is just returning the same now because I still dont know how to access the values inorder to do something**

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: I just want to know how to access both series values individually . as u can see in that output , I get both 1 and 11 in that above format .. but I want to get only 1 or only 11

Comment: This is a bit unclear to me. Your function just prints first row. If you could tell me what are you trying to achieve, maybe I can help.

Comment: okay So the ID you see here is actually a reference to another 2 dataframes that have the same ID .. so i want to extract each element  Like as i said 1 or 11 indvidually . So that i can use that ID to reference other 2 DF's that I have. I can use 2 apply functions individually , I know that works but i want to do it in one as shown above for reducing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a parameter `axis=1` to your apply function, like

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """
    ,ID1,ID2
   0,1,11
   1,2,12
   2,3,13
   3,4,14
   4,5,15
   5,6,16
   6,7,17
   7,8,18
   8,9,19
   9,10,20
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),index_col=0)

def funct(row):
    # return row

    # update the answer
    return pd.Series([row.ID1 + 100, row.ID2 + 20])

df[['s1','s2']] = df[['ID1',"ID2"]].apply(funct, axis=1)
```

Comment: Okay So the ID you see here is actually a reference to another 2 dataframes that have the same ID .. so i want to extract each element Like as i said 1 or 11 indvidually . So that i can use that ID to reference other 2 DF's that I have. I can use 2 apply functions individually , I know that works but i want to do it in one as shown above for reducing time

Comment: I will accept the answer because the axis = 1 was what was missing . Thank you . now i can access using row[0] and row[1]

Comment: You can define your own function apply on one row, using the column name to access the row's element, such as `row.ID1` .